# Applying custom css to Bootstrap input type text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I spent an hour trying to apply my css to Bootstrap input of type text inside a form. Here's my code:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" class="form-control" />
  </div>
</form>

input [type=text] {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

The strange thing is that if I remove the `[type=text]` part, then all is ok.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wucomkbs/)

Comment: Sorry for misprint in the work `background`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the space between `input` and `[type=text]`:

```css
input[type=text] {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<input type="password"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background spelling is wrong and remove space.

```
input [type=text] {
  barckground-color: red !important;
}
```

so make sure you type correct.

```
input[type=text] {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try this one hope i can help you:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usr">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="input username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="input password">
    </div>
</form>
```